# Facebook JS SDK not loading in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, facebook, browser, safari

My Facebook App works fine in all browsers except in Safari 5.1.7 on MAC and Windows.
The Facebook JS SDK is not loading correct.
I have the FB.getLoginStatus and AutoGrow function in use, 
but Safari ignores this and gets my a blank screen.

I also use jQuery. No problems with it.

The strange thing is, that on Safari 6 all things work correct.

Has anybody the same problems or a fix for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste you console error and warnings that you get at least? Go to developer console, and then hit cmd+shit+I and check the error at the debugger tab.

Comment: There are no errors in the logs...

Comment: can you update it with your code? parts of it at least so I can help you further?